# Pyomo Variable-Initialization

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm trying to make piecewise-linear LPs work with the glpk-solver in pyomo, but I'm struggling with variable initialization.
A 2-dimensional variable lambda is specified.

When no initial value is specified for the variable, I encounter errors after solving it.
This is to be a part of a self-made branch-and-bound algorithm, so the initial values will change, and I haven't been able to find any way of initializing the 2-dimensional variable with a matrix. (All k lambdas in the NxK variable should sum to one for feasibility, so they can't be identical)

Is it possible to have the solver search for an arbitrary, feasible initial point by itself?

For AbstractModels, can variables in some way be initialized as a function of other model parameters?
(The problem is to solve N piecewise-linear optimization problems, which is to be solved using convex combinations)

Parameters and sets for the ConcreteModels are initialized using a .dat-file and a DataPortal.

Edit: The whole script is included

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Sep 16 21:26:33 2020

@author: lsi
"""

from pyomo.environ import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import compress, product
import random
def combinations(items):
    return ( list(compress(items,mask)) for mask in product(*[[0,1]]*len(items)) )
# %% Data extraction:
random.seed(1000)

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='p2.dat')
data_list = [tup[1] for tup in list(data.items())]
N = data_list[0]
setN = data_list[1]
setK = data_list[2]
K = [data_list[5][n+1] for n in range(N)]
lb_inj = [data_list[6][n+1] for n in range(N)]
ub_inj = [data_list[7][n+1] for n in range(N)]
Qinj_max = data_list[8]
Qliq_max = data_list[9]
Qgas_max = data_list[10]
WCut = [data_list[11][n+1] for n in range(N)]
GOR = [data_list[12][n+1] for n in range(N)]
Qinj = [[data_list[13][n+1,k+1] for k in range(K[n])]for n in range(N)]
Qoil = [[data_list[14][n+1,k+1] for k in range(K[n])]for n in range(N)]




# %% create model
m = AbstractModel()

m.N = Param() # number of wells
m.setN = Set()

m.K = Param(m.setN) # number of breakpoint for each well "n"
m.setK = Set() # set of breakpoints for each well

m.setNK = Set()
m.setN_KEND = Set()

m.Qinj = Param(m.setN,m.setK,domain=NonNegativeReals)
m.Qoil = Param(m.setN,m.setK,domain=NonNegativeReals)

m.Qinj_max = Param(domain=NonNegativeReals)
m.Qliq_max = Param(domain=NonNegativeReals)
m.Qgas_max = Param(domain=NonNegativeReals)

m.GOR = Param(m.setN)
m.WCut = Param(m.setN)

m.lb_inj = Param(m.setN)
m.ub_inj = Param(m.setN)

m.y = Var(m.setN, bounds = (0,1), within=NonNegativeReals)#, initialize=0)
m.Qinj_var = Var(m.setN, within=NonNegativeReals)#, initialize= max(_inj))
m.Qoil_var = Var(m.setN, within=NonNegativeReals)#, initialize=0)
m.Qw_var = Var(m.setN, within=NonNegativeReals)#, initialize=0)
m.Qg_var = Var(m.setN, within=NonNegativeReals)#, initialize=0)
m.lbd = Var(m.setNK, bounds=(0,1), within=NonNegativeReals)
# m.lbd[1,:].set_value(1)




# %% Objective
def objRule(m):
    return sum(m.Qoil_var[:])

# %% Well constraints
def inj_constraint(m):
    return sum(m.Qinj_var[k] for k in m.setN) <= m.Qinj_max
def liq_constraint(m):
    return sum(m.Qoil_var[k] + m.Qw_var[k] for k in m.setN) <= m.Qliq_max
def gas_constraint(m):
    return sum(m.Qinj_var) + sum(m.Qg_var) <= m.Qgas_max
def q_g_constraint(m, i):
    return m.Qg_var[i] == m.GOR[i] * m.Qoil_var[i]
def q_w_constraint(m,i):
    return m.Qw_var[i] == m.WCut[i]/(1-m.WCut[i]) * m.Qoil_var[i]
def q_inj_binary_constraint_lb(m,i):
    return m.Qinj_var[i] >= m.lb_inj[i]*m.y[i]
def q_inj_binary_constraint_ub(m,i):
    return m.Qinj_var[i] <= m.ub_inj[i]*m.y[i]
def y_relaxed_constraint(m,i):
    return m.y[i] <= 1

m.c_inj = Constraint(rule=inj_constraint)
m.c_liq = Constraint(rule=liq_constraint)
m.c_gas = Constraint(rule=gas_constraint)
m.c_q_g = Constraint(m.setN, rule=q_g_constraint)
m.c_q_w = Constraint(m.setN, rule=q_w_constraint)
m.c_q_inj_bin_lb = Constraint(m.setN, rule=q_inj_binary_constraint_lb)
m.c_q_inj_bin_ub = Constraint(m.setN, rule=q_inj_binary_constraint_ub)
m.c_y_relaxed = Constraint(m.setN, rule=y_relaxed_constraint)



# %% Convex Combination Constraints
m.z = Var(m.setNK, bounds=(0,1),within=NonNegativeReals)#, initialize=0)

def CC_x_constraint(m,n):
    Qinj_n = list(m.Qinj[n,:])
    return  sum([m.lbd[n,k+1] * Qinj_n[k] for k in range(K[n-1])])== m.Qinj_var[n]
def CC_y_constraint(m,n):
    Qoil_n = list(m.Qoil[n,:])
    return  sum([m.lbd[n,k+1] * Qoil_n[k] for k in range(K[n-1])])== m.Qoil_var[n]
def CC_lbd_sum_constraint(m,n):
    return 1 == sum(m.lbd[n,:])
def CC_lbd_k_constraint(m,n,k):
    return m.lbd[n,k] <= m.z[n,k]
def CC_lbd_end_constraint(m,n,k):
    return m.lbd[n,k] <= m.z[n,k]
def CC_z_relaxed_constraint(m,i,j):
    return m.z[i,j] <= 1
def CC_z_constraint(m,n):
    return sum(m.z[n,:]) == 1

m.CC_x = Constraint(m.setN, rule=CC_x_constraint)
m.CC_y = Constraint(m.setN, rule=CC_y_constraint)
m.CC_lbd = Constraint(m.setN,rule=CC_lbd_sum_constraint)
m.CC_lbd_k = Constraint(m.setNK, rule=CC_lbd_k_constraint)
m.CC_lbd_end = Constraint(m.setN_KEND, rule=CC_lbd_end_constraint)
m.CC_z_relaxed = Constraint(m.setNK, rule=CC_z_relaxed_constraint)
m.CC_z = Constraint(m.setN,rule=CC_z_constraint)

m.OBJ = Objective(rule=objRule, sense=maximize)

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')

m_instance = m.create_instance(data)
#%%


# %% Random branching

def random_y_branches(m):
    is_fixed_list = [m_instance.y[k+1].is_fixed() for k in range(N)]
    is_fixed_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(is_fixed_list) if not x]
    if np.any(is_fixed_indices):
        fix_index = random.choice(is_fixed_indices)
    
        m_left = m.clone()
        m_right = m.clone()
        
        m_left.y[fix_index].fix(1)
        m_right.y[fix_index].fix(0)
        return [m_left, m_right]
    else:
        return -1

def random_z_branches(m):
    is_fixed_list = [m_instance.z[n+1,k+1].is_fixed() for k,n in np.ndindex(*K,N)]
    is_fixed_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(is_fixed_list) if not x]
    if np.any(is_fixed_indices):
        index_set = list(m_instance.z.index_set())
        fix_index = index_set[random.choice(is_fixed_indices)]    
        m_left = m.clone()
        m_right = m.clone()
        
        m_left.z[fix_index].fix(1)
        m_right.z[fix_index].fix(0)
        return [m_left, m_right]
    else:
        return -1
# %% Branch-And_Bound Algorithm

active_set = random_z_branches(m_instance)

while active_set:
    j = active_set.pop()
    j.lbd[1,:].set_value(1)
    opt.solve(j)
    
    
    


# %% Plot
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(num=1)
K = m_instance.K.sparse_values()
Qoil_vals = m_instance.Qoil.sparse_values()
Qinj_vals = m_instance.Qinj.sparse_values()
Qoil_vec = []
Qinj_vec = []
ind = 0
for i in range(len(K)):
    ax1.plot(Qinj[i], Qoil[i], label='Well'+str(i))
    ind += K[i]
ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

Data-file:

```
#---------------

table N := 1;

set setN := 1; 
set setK := 1 2 3 4 5 6;
set setNK := 
   (1, 1)
   (1, 2)
   (1, 3)
   (1, 4)
   (1, 5)
   (1, 6);
set setN_KEND :=
    (1,6);

param K := 
   1 6;

param lb_inj := 
   1 225;

   
param ub_inj := 
   1 1485;

table Qinj_max := 50;
#param Qinj_max := 1000;
#param Qinj_max := 1500;

table Qliq_max := 5500;
table Qgas_max := 6000;


param WCut := 
   1 0.4567;
 
param GOR := 
   1 1.9642;

   
table Qinj(n,k) Qoil(n,k):
  n k Qinj Qoil:=
  1 1 0.000000 0.000000
  1 2 225.000000 290.000000
  1 3 314.000000 324.000000
  1 4 672.000000 386.000000
  1 5 768.000000 391.000000
  1 6 1485.000000 433.000000

;
```

Edit: Here is the output from the last solved model j when typing j.display():

```
j.display()
Model unknown

  Variables:
    y : Size=1, Index=setN
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
    Qinj_var : Size=1, Index=setN
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
    Qoil_var : Size=1, Index=setN
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
    Qw_var : Size=1, Index=setN
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
    Qg_var : Size=1, Index=setN
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
    lbd : Size=6, Index=setNK
        Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (1, 1) :     0 :     1 :     1 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 2) :     0 :     1 :     1 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 3) :     0 :     1 :     1 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 4) :     0 :     1 :     1 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 5) :     0 :     1 :     1 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 6) :     0 :     1 :     1 : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    z : Size=6, Index=setNK
        Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (1, 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 2) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 3) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 4) :     0 :     1 :     1 :  True :  True : Binary
        (1, 5) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 6) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

  Objectives:
    OBJ : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: OBJ
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.objective.SimpleObjective'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object OBJ
        Key : Active : Value
        None :   None :  None

  Constraints:
    c_inj : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :  None : None :  50.0
    c_liq : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Qoil_var[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Qoil_var[1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :  None : None :  None
    c_gas : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :  None :  2.0 : 6000.0
    c_q_g : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Qg_var[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Qg_var[1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :  None
    c_q_w : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Qw_var[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Qw_var[1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :  None
    c_q_inj_bin_lb : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: y[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object y[1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :  None
    c_q_inj_bin_ub : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Qinj_var[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Qinj_var[1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :  None
    c_y_relaxed : Size=1
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :   1.0
    CC_x : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Qinj_var[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Qinj_var[1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :  None
    CC_y : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Qoil_var[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Qoil_var[1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :  None
    CC_lbd : Size=1
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :   1.0 :    6 :   1.0
    CC_lbd_0 : Size=1
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: z[1,1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,1]
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          1 :  None : None :  None
    CC_lbd_k : Size=5
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: z[1,1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,1]
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: z[1,2]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,2]
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: z[1,3]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,3]
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: z[1,5]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,5]
```

Comment: I don't think glpk can use initial values. I suspect that is mostly for NLPs (and may be MIPSTARTs for some solvers). LP solvers typically don't use initial values but rather an advanced basis. Some MIP solvers accept initial integer variables to branch towards.

Comment: I tried solving without initial values, which results in the added output.

Comment: You may want to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I've added the whole script